# String.split with regexp bug

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to split a string by a variable number of successive characters

> splitBy4('XXXXXXXX') => ['XXXX', 'XXXX']

Before injecting the variable it worked all fine :

```
console.log('XXXXXXXX'.split(/(\w{4})/).filter(Boolean));
// outputs : ['XXXX', 'XXXX']
console.log('XXXXXXXX'.split(new RegExp(/(\w{4})/)).filter(Boolean));
// outputs : ['XXXX', 'XXXX']
```

But when I try to use the `RegExp` class + string representation (to inject my parameter), it fails :

```
console.log('XXXXXXXX'.split(new RegExp('(\w{4})')).filter(Boolean));
// outputs ['XXXXXXXX']

const nb = 4;
console.log('XXXXXXXX'.split(new RegExp('(\w{'+ nb +'})')).filter(Boolean));
// outputs ['XXXXXXXX']
```

What am I missing and how can I inject my parameter ?
Thanks

Comment: Cf. `console.log('\w')` and `console.log('\\w')`.

Comment: Well ... thanks ;)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
const nb = "4";
var myRegex = new RegExp('(\\w{' + nb + '})', 'g');
var myArray = myRegex.exec('XXXXXXXX');
console.log(myArray.toString());
```